# How to apply Category rule to shopping cart rules in Magento?

Tags: magento, categories, cart

I have problem with Magento (ver. 1.7.0.2) applying the rule only to cart items matching following conditions:
- The request of rule is: When customer buy 2 or more items, the item with lowest price get 50 % discount amount **but** this rule should apply for all categories except one category.

So first I did this:
Apply: Zero-1-Buy X get the cheapest free
Discount Amount: 50
Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 2

[image: first rule - discount 50 % of cheapest item if buy 2]

Now this first rule works fine, we can see in web page, that discount of 50 % is added to second item, witch is cheapest:

[image: rule 1 - works]

**But if I whant** that this rule is not applyed for specific "Category" this is not working.

This is what I tried:

```
If ALL of these contitions are TRUE:
  Category is not 9
```

[image: rule that not work]

I have tried all combinations, that is not in cat. 9 but that is in all other categories, same thing I have try with "Conditions" (like: Not Found Item in category 9). I have also tried to reindex after saving rule. But it is not solving my problem, Item with lowest price from this specific category (9) if added to cart and it is second or more Item in Cart it gets discount of 50 %.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> If ALL of these conditions are **FALSE**
>       Category **is** 9

Comment: No effect, It still discount from category 9.